# Как в Composer сделать update только одного плагина?

Tags: php, composer

У меня в проекте соедини много плагинов но нужно сделать update только одного или двух плагинов ,  как можно это сделать ?

Что нужно сделать с composer.lock  файлом чтобы update произошел, если ее удалить то как понимаю composer сделает update  всех плагинов, чего я не хочу , если оставить то он не позволит сделать update?

Comment: https://phpprofi.ru/blogs/post/52

Comment: `composer` - выводит список команд с кратким описанием. `composer help`  - помощь по команде. `composer help update` и получите `update [options] [--] [<packages>]...` а внизу еще и примерчики `php composer.phar update vendor/package1 foo/mypackage` и `php composer.phar update vendor/package1 foo/*`

Answer (score 0):

```
composer update название_пакета
```